# How do I take a screenshot of an active phone call without hanging up?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the "hard-pause" dialing feature. If you put a semicolon after a phone number you can provide, for example, a conference line pass-code as part of a phone number.

```
1-800-123-4567;987654#
```

The call screen then shows a little clickable label in the bottom left-hand side of the call screen to appear

```
Dial "9876..."
```

I try to screenshot that, but pressing the home button causes the call to end and I get a screenshot of the hanging up call screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Assistive Touch, available from Settings → Accessibility → Assistive Touch.

Enable the feature using the switch, then take a screenshot by pressing the Assistive Touch button, then Device → More → Screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac you could use QuickTime Player?

Connect iPhone to Mac > Open QT Player > Make sure iPhone is unlocked > New Movie Recording > in the new window: Pick Source Camera as 'Name Of iPhone' > Phone screen should show up on the computer.

From there make the call and screenshot it on the Mac.